# Who are these New Gods shown in Justice League: Gods and Monsters?

Tags: dc, character-identification, justice-league-gods-and-monsters

In the movie ***Justice League: Gods and Monsters*** who are these New Gods shown? I can identify the ones which are named in movie like Bekka, Darkseid, Highfather, and Orion. I want to identify the ones which are marked in the screenshots given below

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Lightray](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Solis_(Gods_and_Monsters))
2. [Mister Miracle](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Scott_Free_(Gods_and_Monsters))
3. [Granny Goodness](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Granny_Goodness_(Gods_and_Monsters))
4. [Steppenwolf](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Steppenwolf_(Gods_and_Monsters))
5. [Kalibak](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Kalibak_(Gods_and_Monsters))
6. [Big Barda](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Big_Barda_(Gods_and_Monsters))